# How many instances are created on generic class instantiation?

Tags: c#, java, generics, instantiation

Consider such class:

```
class Foo<T>
{
   private T myField;
   public void Set(T x)
   {
      myField = x;
   }
}
```

And then you instantiate it with `T` equal to `int`, `bool` (value types) and `String`, `List`.

How may instantiations will be created and how they would look like?

**I am interested in Java and C#.**

*From what I read Java would create one general class with basically casting, while in C# there would be two classes for `int` and `bool` plus single one for `String` and `List` because they are reference values (is this true? what about static fields?).*

Comment: Instances of what? Instantiations aren't _created_.

Comment: What you're describing isn't even valid in Java - you can't create `Foo<int>`. And in C# `List` is a generic type, assuming you mean System.Collections.Generic.List.

Comment: Are you coming from a C++ background, perhaps? Your question doesn't really make sense for C# and Java.

Comment: @TimS. I am simply curious about mechanism of using generics (from compiler POV), because unlike C++ (yes, this is my background) generic classes are precompiled and then used.

Comment: @JonSkeet, so in Java generics are only for reference types, thanks. I am interested what happens (in compiler) when you type `new Foo<String>()` and then the same with `List`. Both instances would have some type, right? Is `Set` is the same (shared) or not? And so on.

Comment: You'd need to define exactly what you mean by shared for the question to have any meaning.

Comment: The number of instantiated objects has literally nothing to do with generics.  Every time the constructor is called, a new object instance is created.  This is equally true of generic and non-generic types.

Comment: Are you maybe referring to the _type definitions_? That is, I can manually create 1000 _instances_ of `Foo<int>` via `var myIntFoo = new Foo<int>()`, but there's only 1 type definition (upon which information about the method bodies, reflection information, stuff in the `System.Type` representation, maybe even `static` members)? Are you asking that if I have both a `Foo<int>` and a `Foo<bool>`, is any of the type information shared between them or essentially duplicated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note here I'm assuming regular CLR - no AOT etc.

At the IL level: there is one definition of `Foo<T>`; the IL is identical (shared) no matter the `T`.

At the JIT level: the type is jitted (per generic parameter) **once** for **all** (shared) reference-type parameters, and once *each* (separately) value-type parameters. So the JIT for `Foo<string>` and `Foo<List<...>>` is shared, and a separate JIT for each of `Foo<int>` and `Foo<bool>`.

The number of objects/instances created is identical to the number of `new Foo<...>(...)` calls (or `Activator.CreateInstance(...)` etc).

Comment: I did not know the multiple `Foo<?>`s were actually created at the JIT, not the IL compile phase, useful information. Thanks

Comment: @IvayloSlavov just note that some AOT compilers do ... tricks there.

Comment: I assume so. I know since .NET 4.0 we have more dynamic behavior of static members (being kinda JITTED). Does your post apply to pre-4.0 versions of the CLR also (the 2.0 version, 1.1 did not support generics at all)?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov yes; the exception is things like iOS compilers, that don't use JIT at runtime

Answer (score 4):

In the JVM, there is one and only one class: the one that results from type erasure.

In the CLR, a closed type is constructed for each value of the type parameter, each with its own distinct copies of static fields; JIT code sharing between closed types with reference-typed arguments is an implementation optimization.  Therefore, while `Foo<String>` and `Foo<List>` might reference the same JIT-translated method implementation, they are not the same type and would have distinct static fields.

Answer (score 3):

Java Generics are implemented by "type erasure".

The compiler creates one class `Foo<T>`, which essentially has the code `Foo<Object>` would have.  It is not like a C++ template where a new class is instantiated based on the types.  It's quicker to compile than the C++ version, but does prevent some optimizations from occurring at compile time.  I believe the main rationale for this system was the desire to maintain compatibility with pre-Generics Java.

The type parameters, *e.g.* the `Integer` in `Foo<Integer>` are only used at compile time to issue an error if the programmer attempts to pass a `Bar` in, and to allow the compiler to assume that functions returning `T` will return a `T`, whereas in pre-Generics Java the programmer would have to cast the result.  It is also worth noting that none of the methods of `Foo<Integer>` will actually check that their arguments are `Integer`s unless the programmer writes this explicitly.

As for static fields, because there is only one `Foo` instead of separate `Foo`s for different specializations, the type variable is "non-static" and attempting to declare a static member of type `T` doesn't make sense.  On my compiler, it fails with the error "non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context".

Answer (score 2):

Java and .NET handle generics differently. Let's take a look at the following piece of code:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private static Object staticMember;

    public T getStaticMember() { 
        return (T) staticMember; 
    }

    private T instanceMember;

    public T getInstanceMember() {
        return instanceMember;
    }

    public Foo(T value)
    {
        if (staticMember == null) 
        {
            staticMember = value;
        }
        this.instanceMember = value;
    }        
}
```

This is not good code in terms of quality, but for the sake of the example, it is a working piece of code for both Java and C#.

In Java, the runtime only knows about the class `Foo`. So the following code

```
Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>(3);
System.out.println(foo.getStaticMember()); // >> 3
System.out.println(foo.getInstanceMember()); // >> 3
```

will actually be compiled to something similar:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(3);
System.out.println(((Integer) foo.getInstanceMember()).toString()); // 3
System.out.println(((Integer) foo.getStaticMember()).toString()); // 3
```

As you can see, the generic is translated into type cast for the static member.

The following code then will fail in Java with a runtime exception:

```
Foo<Integer> foo1 = new Foo<Integer>(3);
Foo<String> foo2 = new Foo<String>("This is a string");
System.out.println(foo1.getInstanceMember()); // >> 3
System.out.println(foo2.getInstanceMember()); // >> This is a string
System.out.println(foo1.getStaticMember()); // >> 3
System.out.println(foo2.getStaticMember()); // Invalid cast exception
```

because it will be treated as:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo(3);
Foo foo2 = new Foo("This is a string");
System.out.println(((Integer) foo1.getInstanceMember()).toString()); // >> 3
System.out.println(((String) foo2.getInstanceMember()).toString()); 
// >> This is a string
System.out.println(((Integer) foo1.getStaticMember()).toString()); // >> 3
System.out.println(((String) foo2.getStaticMember()).toString()); 
// Invalid cast exception
```

The last line would attempt to cast the static member, which is `Integer` to `String`.

The above code will work fine in C#, printing respectively:

> 3
> 3
> This is a string
> This is a string

### Why?

#### How Java works

In Java, the compiler creates the `Foo` class as a raw type, ignoring any generic information in the type definition. This is known as **type erasure** ([also explained in Samuel Edwin Ward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767500/795158)). The compiler, will try to detect (or better said - guess) the type usages and attempt compensate the type erasure by adding type casts in the generated code, analyzing the uses of the class in order to achieve this. So, in general, the result will be as if the type `Foo` was generic. The problem is that the type `Foo` exists only once, and its `staticMember` is one and the same instance that is shared between `Foo<Integer>` and `Foo<String>`.

#### How .NET works

In .NET, the `Foo<int>` and `Foo<string>` declarations result in generating distinct types during compile time (actually in the JIT phase, as [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767056/how-many-instances-are-created-on-generic-class-instantiation/23767262#23767262) and [Jeffrey Hantin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767477/795158) clarify in their respective answers). So, the `Foo<string>` class is a completely different type than the `Foo<int>`. This causes each of them to have its own `staticMember` property, so it is guaranteed that the `Foo<string>.staticMember` is always of the `string` type, and the `Foo<int>.staticMember` is a completely different member of an `int` type.

Comment: Your class does not compile with javac 1.7.0_55: "non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard, you are correct, thanks for pointing out. I must have used too much C# stuff. I updated the code. This error is a good addition to the topic, that in Java generics should not be used for static members.

Comment: Wow, thank you (and thank you all), with so many great answers it is hard to pick one to mark as the accepted one. I hope you don't mind I will stick with Marc Gravell, who was first to answer.

Comment: @greenoldman, no problem. After all, the point of the site is to serve as a knowledge base for causes and solutions to technical problems, so more than one answer is actually very common here.